# display scrollable text in a Spritekit Scene (Swift)

Tags: text, swift

What is the best way to display a block of scrollable text in a Spritekit game? This will be within the scene. I could write my own algorithm using SKLabels but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no component in SpriteKit to do that out of the box, but it's quite simple to simulate a scrolling text handling touches.

You would have to handle limit and paging if you want to have it as well as bouncing, acceleration and others, but there are plenty of examples around here to start from. Also keep in mind that `SKLabelNode` doesn't support multiline out of the box, so you would have to create your own MultiLine label (basically 1 label per line).

If the text you want to render is very long it may struggle to create it and not be very smooth, but will work fine.

The other option is to use UIKit which makes it very simple to create that using `UIScrollView` and `UITextView` and present it on top of your SKView that contains your scene. Obviously this doesn't work if you really need it to be within the scene but works wonders if you want to display big chunks of texts for instructions or legal texts.